# How to declare 4d String array in android studio?

Tags: java, android

This is what I have right now but I know its wrong. I know it needs an array initializer but i'm not sure how much space for array index I need. Right now I just need to declare a 4d String array.

```
String[][][][] array = new String[][][][];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the sizes, e.g.

`String[][][][] array = new String[10][10][10][10];`